# setting pandas sub-series to list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series that looks like this:

```
(all, timestamp, value)    NaN
(1, Ax, value)             NaN
(1, Ay, value)             NaN
...
(1, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
(2, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
(3, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
(4, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
(5, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
(6, gyro_enabled, value)   NaN
```

I have the following list:

`gyr_en =                [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

I would like to set each `(i, gyro_enabled, value)` to their corresponding value in `gyr_en`.

I cannot figure out how to do this, other than just looping through gyr_en and setting each value separately. Is there a more pandas-ish way to do this?

As opposed to this:

```
        for i in range(0, 6):
            idx = i
            imu_name = i+1
            new_row[imu_name, 'gyro_enabled', 'value'] = gyr_en[i]
```

Which produces the following:

```
(all, p-count, value)       NaN
(all, timestamp, value)     NaN
(1, Ax, value)              NaN
(1, Ay, value)              NaN
(1, Az, value)              NaN
(1, Gx, value)              NaN
(1, Gy, value)              NaN
(1, Gz, value)              NaN
(2, Ax, value)              NaN
...
(6, Gx, value)              NaN
(6, Gy, value)              NaN
(6, Gz, value)              NaN
(6, T, value)               NaN
(integrated, Ax, value)     NaN
(integrated, Ay, value)     NaN
(integrated, Az, value)     NaN
(integrated, Gx, value)     NaN
(integrated, Gy, value)     NaN
(integrated, Gz, value)     NaN
(integrated, T, value)      NaN
(1, gyro_enabled, value)    0.0
(2, gyro_enabled, value)    1.0
(3, gyro_enabled, value)    1.0
(4, gyro_enabled, value)    1.0
(5, gyro_enabled, value)    1.0
(6, gyro_enabled, value)    1.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: how do you do a looping through gyr_en and finding the corresponding value? Please provide us sample result. Is i the index of gyr_en? Thanks.

Comment: Too many ambiguities.  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have done that.

Comment: Was responding to anonymous.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `pandas.Series` is named `s`

```
from operator import itemgetter

s.loc[s.index.map(itemgetter(1)) == 'gyro_enabled'] = gyr_en
```